# Ajuda com organização de função

Tags: php, ip

Estou desenvolvendo uma calculadora IP, e agora preciso achar o primeiro IP válido da rede original digitada. Eu separei meu código em funções, o que acho que ao em vez de ajudar, atrapalhou. Meu problema é o seguinte: Eu tenho uma função que exibe máscara e nessa função eu tenho os octetos digitados e separados (cada octeto é uma string). Eu tenho uma função que calcula o ID da rede, porém, essa função é chamada fora das funções, pois preciso passar por parâmetro a máscara e o endereço ip. A função que exibe a máscara retorna a máscara e a função que exibe o endereço retorna o endereço, então pego esses valores em duas variáveis e passo quando chamo a função ID. Agora, pra calcular o primeiro IP válido, eu preciso do último octeto (está na função máscara), mas também preciso dos parâmetros máscara e endereço, pois o primeiro IP válido é o endereço de ID + 1 (somando isso no último octeto). O problema está na hora de pegar esses valores, uma vez que os octetos estão na função máscara.

Minha função máscara

```
       function exibe_mascara() { //função pra exibir informações da máscara original da rede
        $mascara_bin = array("", "", "", ""); //array pra máscara em binário
        $conta_octeto = 0; //variável para contar os octetos da máscara
        $conta_bit = 0; // variável pra contar os bits da máscara
        $stringMascaraBin = null; //inicializa a variavel de string da mascara binario

        if ($_POST["mascara"] >= 8 && $_POST["mascara"] <= 30 || valida_mascara_decimal()) { //condição pra validar o que o cara digitou
            if ($_POST["mascara"] >= 8 && $_POST["mascara"] <= 30) { //condição p testar se a máscara está em notação CIDR 
                for ($j = 0; $j < $_POST["mascara"]; $j++) { //laço para acrescentar "1" na máscara de acordo com a máscara CIDR
                    $mascara_bin[$conta_octeto] = $mascara_bin[$conta_octeto] . "1";
                    $conta_bit++;
                    if ($conta_bit == 8 || $conta_bit == 16 || $conta_bit == 24) {//condição pra incrementar o octeto
                        $conta_octeto++;
                    }
                }

                $limite = 32 - $_POST["mascara"]; //conta pra saber quantos bits sobraram pra host
                for ($i = 0; $i < $limite; $i++) { //laço para acrescentar os bits de host, os zero's.
                    $mascara_bin[$conta_octeto] = $mascara_bin[$conta_octeto] . "0";
                    $conta_bit++;
                    if ($conta_bit == 8 || $conta_bit == 16 || $conta_bit == 24) {//condição pra incrementar o octeto
                        $conta_octeto++;
                    }
                }
                echo"<br>";
                echo"Máscara em binário: &nbsp;";

                for ($i = 0; $i < count($mascara_bin); $i++) {//exibir a máscara em binário
                    echo $mascara_bin[$i];
                }


                echo"<br>";
                echo"Máscara em notação CIDR: &nbsp;/" . $_POST["mascara"] . "<br>";
                echo"Máscara em decimal: &nbsp;";
                $mascara_decimal = array("", "", "", ""); //array pra máscara em decimal
                for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {//laço pra exibir a máscara em decimal
                    echo bindec($mascara_bin[$i]);
                    $mascara_decimal[$i] = bindec($mascara_bin[$i]);
                    if ($i < 3) {
                        echo".";
                    }
                }
                //separa os octetos em arrays 
                $octeto1 = str_split($mascara_bin[0]);
                $octeto2 = str_split($mascara_bin[1]);
                $octeto3 = str_split($mascara_bin[2]);
                $octeto4 = str_split($mascara_bin[3]);


                //chamada da função wildcard
                echo "<br> Wildcard binário: &nbsp;";
                $octeto1_wil = wildcard($octeto1);
                echo ".";
                $octeto2_wil = wildcard($octeto2);
                echo ".";
                $octeto3_wil = wildcard($octeto3);
                echo ".";
                $octeto4_wil = wildcard($octeto4);
                echo "<br>";

                //inicializando as strings para os octetos
                $stringArrayF1 = null;
                $stringArrayF2 = null;
                $stringArrayF3 = null;
                $stringArrayF4 = null;

                //transformando os arrays de octetos wildcard em strings
                foreach ($octeto1_wil as $stringArray1) {
                    $stringArrayF1 = $stringArrayF1 . $stringArray1;
                }


                foreach ($octeto2_wil as $stringArray2) {
                    $stringArrayF2 = $stringArrayF2 . $stringArray2;
                }


                foreach ($octeto3_wil as $stringArray3) {
                    $stringArrayF3 = $stringArrayF3 . $stringArray3;
                }


                foreach ($octeto4_wil as $stringArray4) {
                    $stringArrayF4 = $stringArrayF4 . $stringArray4;
                }

                $aux = 0; //variável pra mudar a posição do vetor endereço
                $endereco_ip = explode(".", $_POST["endereco"]); //tirar os pontos do endereço digitado
                echo "Endereço de Broadcast: &nbsp;";
                //chamada da função de broadcast
                broadcast($stringArrayF1, $endereco_ip, $aux);
                $aux++;
                broadcast($stringArrayF2, $endereco_ip, $aux);
                $aux++;
                broadcast($stringArrayF3, $endereco_ip, $aux);
                $aux++;
                $ultimo_octeto = broadcast($stringArrayF4, $endereco_ip, $aux); //armazena o ultimo octeto de broadcast numa variavel


                echo "<br>Último IP válido: &nbsp;";
                $aux = 0;

                //chamada da função de ultimo ip valido
                UltimoIpValido($stringArrayF1, $endereco_ip, $aux, $ultimo_octeto);
                $aux++;
                UltimoIpValido($stringArrayF2, $endereco_ip, $aux, $ultimo_octeto);
                $aux++;
                UltimoIpValido($stringArrayF3, $endereco_ip, $aux, $ultimo_octeto);
                $aux++;
                UltimoIpValido($stringArrayF4, $endereco_ip, $aux, $ultimo_octeto);


                foreach ($mascara_bin as $stringMascara) { //transforma em string o array de mascara binario
                    $stringMascaraBin = $stringMascaraBin . $stringMascara;
                }

                return $stringMascaraBin; //retorna a string da mascara em binario
            }



            if (valida_mascara_decimal()) { //chama a função de validar pra saber se está no formato correto
                $mascara_decimal = array("", "", "", ""); //array pra mascara em decimal
                $mascara_decimal = explode(".", $_POST["mascara"]); //adicionando a máscara digitada ao array de mascara decimal sem os pontos
                $mascara_binario = array("", "", "", ""); //cria array pra mascara em binario
                echo "Máscara em decimal:&nbsp;";
                echo $_POST["mascara"] . "<br>"; //exibe a mascara em decimal
                echo "Máscara em binário:&nbsp;";
                for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {//laço pra transformar de decimal pra binario e armazenar no array mascara binario
                    $mascara_binario[$i] = str_pad(decbin($mascara_decimal[$i]), 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); //transforma a posição i da mascara em decimal em binario e armazena na posição i da mascara em binário e adiciona 0 a esquerda caso o numero em binario n tenha preenchido  bits
                    if ($i < 4 && $i > 0) {
                        echo"."; //coloca os pontos nos octetos
                    }
                    echo $mascara_binario[$i]; //exibe a mascara binario
                }


                //separa os octetos em arrays
                $octeto1 = str_split($mascara_binario[0]);
                $octeto2 = str_split($mascara_binario[1]);
                $octeto3 = str_split($mascara_binario[2]);
                $octeto4 = str_split($mascara_binario[3]);


                //chama função pra saber quais bits estão setados
                $bit_setado_octeto1 = verificarBit($octeto1);
                $bit_setado_octeto2 = verificarBit($octeto2);
                $bit_setado_octeto3 = verificarBit($octeto3);
                $bit_setado_octeto4 = verificarBit($octeto4);

                //chama a função wildcard e adiciona o retorno numa variável
                echo "<br> Wildcard binário: &nbsp;";
                $octeto1_wil = wildcard($octeto1);
                echo ".";
                $octeto2_wil = wildcard($octeto2);
                echo ".";
                $octeto3_wil = wildcard($octeto3);
                echo ".";
                $octeto4_wil = wildcard($octeto4);


                //inicializa as strings com null
                $stringArrayF1 = null;
                $stringArrayF2 = null;
                $stringArrayF3 = null;
                $stringArrayF4 = null;

                //transforma os arrays dos octetos em strings
                foreach ($octeto1_wil as $stringArray1) {
                    $stringArrayF1 = $stringArrayF1 . $stringArray1;
                }


                foreach ($octeto2_wil as $stringArray2) {
                    $stringArrayF2 = $stringArrayF2 . $stringArray2;
                }


                foreach ($octeto3_wil as $stringArray3) {
                    $stringArrayF3 = $stringArrayF3 . $stringArray3;
                }


                foreach ($octeto4_wil as $stringArray4) {
                    $stringArrayF4 = $stringArrayF4 . $stringArray4;
                }


                echo "<br>";
                $aux = 0;
                $endereco_ip = explode(".", $_POST["endereco"]); //armazena na variavel endereço ip o que foi digitado pra usar na função broadcast
                echo "Endereço de Broadcast: &nbsp;";

                //chama a função broadcast passando os parâmetros pedidos
                broadcast($stringArrayF1, $endereco_ip, $aux);
                $aux++;
                broadcast($stringArrayF2, $endereco_ip, $aux);
                $aux++;
                broadcast($stringArrayF3, $endereco_ip, $aux);
                $aux++;
                $ultimo_octeto = broadcast($stringArrayF4, $endereco_ip, $aux); //armazena o último octeto em broadcast numa variavel ultimo octeto

                echo "<br>Último IP válido: &nbsp;";

                //chama a função de ultimo ip valido
                $aux = 0;
                UltimoIpValido($stringArrayF1, $endereco_ip, $aux, $ultimo_octeto);
                $aux++;
                UltimoIpValido($stringArrayF2, $endereco_ip, $aux, $ultimo_octeto);
                $aux++;
                UltimoIpValido($stringArrayF3, $endereco_ip, $aux, $ultimo_octeto);
                $aux++;
                UltimoIpValido($stringArrayF4, $endereco_ip, $aux, $ultimo_octeto);

                //soma a quantidade de bit setado de cada octeto pra mostrar a mascara em notação CIDR
                $cidr = $bit_setado_octeto1 + $bit_setado_octeto2 + $bit_setado_octeto3 + $bit_setado_octeto4;
                echo "<br>Máscara em notação CIDR: &nbsp;" . $cidr;

                foreach ($mascara_binario as $stringMascara) { //transforma em string o array de mascara binario
                    $stringMascaraBin = $stringMascaraBin . $stringMascara;
                }

                return $stringMascaraBin; //retorna a string da mascara em binario
            }
        } else {
            echo "Formato de máscara inválido!";
        }
    }
```

A função de ID

```
 function id_rede_original($ip_bin, $mascara_bin) {
        echo "ID rede original em decimal: &nbsp;";
        $id_original = $ip_bin & $mascara_bin;
        $decimal_id = long2ip(bindec($id_original));
        echo $decimal_id;
        echo "<br>";
        echo "ID rede original em binário: &nbsp;";
        echo $id_original;
    }
```

e Onde eu chamo a função ID e a máscara

```
 if ($metodo == "POST") {
        if (isset($_POST["calcula"])) {

            if (valida_endereco()) {
                $endereco_original_binario = exibe_endereco();
                echo "<br>";
                ?>
                <hr>
                <?php
                $mascara_original_binario = exibe_mascara();
                echo"<br>";
                classe();
                echo"<br>";
                id_rede_original($endereco_original_binario, $mascara_original_binario);
```

Answer (score 3):

Algumas dicas que podem lhe ajudar:

1. Observe o seu problema, e quebre a solução abstraindo de grosso modo o fluxo dos dados.

   - Crie uma função responsavel por tratar e adaptar para o seu sistema as variaveis passadas por GET e POSTS.
   - Separe a parte lógica do seu sistema.
   - Separe a parte de exibição do sistema.

Nota: Você pode criar 3 classes para separar melhor esses processos, ex de fluxo:

```
$requisicao = new prepararRequisicao();

$calculadora = new calculadora();
$calculadora->validaEndereco($requisicao);
echo json_encode($calculadora->pegarResposta());
```

---

2. Sempre quando notar que existe uma função complexa, abstraia para um metodo.

Ex:

```
if ($_POST["mascara"] >= 8 && $_POST["mascara"] <= 30) {
    // Faça alguma coisa...
}
```

Poderia virar:

```
public function checarNotacaoCIDR($mascara) {
    if ($mascara >= 8 && $mascara <= 30) {
        // Faça alguma coisa...
    }
}
```

3. Alguns programadores acreditam que repetir o mesmo código por mais de duas vezes no mesmo local é sinonimo de coisa errada. Então evite fazer isso:

   ```
   $octeto1 = str_split($mascara_bin[0]);
   $octeto2 = str_split($mascara_bin[1]);
   $octeto3 = str_split($mascara_bin[2]);
   $octeto4 = str_split($mascara_bin[3]);

   $bit_setado_octeto1 = verificarBit($octeto1);
   $bit_setado_octeto2 = verificarBit($octeto2);
   $bit_setado_octeto3 = verificarBit($octeto3);
   $bit_setado_octeto4 = verificarBit($octeto4);
   ```

Pode ser facilmente substituido por:

```
foreach ($mascara_bin as $key => $value) {
    $octeto[$key] = str_split($value);
    $bitSetadoOcteto = verificarBit($octeto[$key]);
}
```

---

Espero que tenha ajudado ;)